# Anroid bottomsheet library com.cocosw:bottomsheet

Tags: android

I am trying to use Android BottomShett library, using android studio
Link :https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Code : I did the same code as tutorial in above github link, I put a button  that triggers Bottomsheet as below :

```
   public void testo(View view) {


       new BottomSheet.Builder(this)
               .title("title")
               .sheet(R.menu.menu_bottom_sheet)
               .listener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       switch (which) {
                           case R.id.scan:
                               // q.toast("Help me!");
                               break;
                           case R.id.folder:
                               // q.toast("Help me!");
                               break;
                           case R.id.upload:
                               // q.toast("Help me!");
                               break;
                       }
                   }
               })
               .show();
   }
```

I am getting this error :

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.cocosw.bottomsheet.ClosableSlidingLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:18928)
    at com.cocosw.bottomsheet.BottomSheet.init(BottomSheet.java:157)
    at com.cocosw.bottomsheet.BottomSheet.onCreate(BottomSheet.java:436)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:386)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
    at com.cocosw.bottomsheet.BottomSheet$Builder.show(BottomSheet.java:676)
    at com.supermarket.unopharm.myapplication.MainActivity.testo(MainActivity.java:53)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.cocosw.bottomsheet.ClosableSlidingLayout$ViewDragCallback
    at com.cocosw.bottomsheet.ClosableSlidingLayout.<init>(ClosableSlidingLayout.java:46)
    at com.cocosw.bottomsheet.ClosableSlidingLayout.<init>(ClosableSlidingLayout.java:40)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Any reason to not use the official [BottomSheet](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md) component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar to com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.5.0@aar

source : https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/issues/148

Comment: Changed library to  implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.5.0@aar'

 and Still getting this error when I click  button to display bottomsheet"


Stack trace:  

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick